# How to correctly import custom types in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

I have custom type in `src/@types/app.d.ts` ( `export type AuthKeyT = string` )

I would like to use it in `tsx` react file (using `import { AuthKeyT } from '@types/app'`), but I am getting an error:

> Cannot import type declaration files. Consider importing 'app' instead of '@types/app'

So, when I use `import { AuthKeyT } from 'app'` I am getting:

> Cannot find module 'app'.

So.. what is wrong? How should I import custom type?

I am using typescript `3.7.2` in react app.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the error says, you can't import a `.d.ts` file in TypeScript.

`import ... from 'app'` mean implicitly `import ... from 'app.ts'` or this file doesn't exist so you get the second error.

If you want to use your types using this import, you have to write them in a simple `.ts` file like that:

*src/@types/app.ts:*

```js
export type AuthKeyT = string
```

With this structure you will be able to import this type using:

```js
import { AuthKeyT } from 'app'
```

Comment: And in which cases are used `.d.ts` files?

Comment: If you have a `app.ts` module you will write his types definition in `app.d.ts`. So when you `import ... from 'app'`, TypeScript will also 'import' the definition file becaute it as the same name as the module.

Comment: what is situation to use ==> 
 import type { somthing } from  './typefile' ;

Comment: In my case, by removing the @ from the folder name, I was able to import without showing errors. Ex. `src/types/config.ts`

Answer (score 65):

You're facing this error because `@types/...` is a global import. For example `import { AuthKeyT } from '@types/app'` means your're trying to import from @types that is in node_modules.

You can fix this by changing `@types` to something like `@customTypes` or by changing the path for your types folder something like `@src/types...` while importing.

Comment: ah, you saved me some hair, friend

Comment: @borgmater I hope you saved some hair in this year as well

Comment: going downhill by the year :-(

Comment: yep, I used alias in tsconfig but eslint error still appeared. This fixed the issue

Answer (score 3):

You can also add `path` to your compilterOptons in the `tsconfig.json` like this:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "types/*": [
        "./@types/*"
      ]
    }
}
```

and then `import { AuthKeyT } from 'types/app'`